# git apply fails with "patch does not apply" error

Tags: git, patch, git-patch

I have a certain patch called my_pcc_branch.patch.

When I try to apply it, I get following message:

```
$ git apply --check my_pcc_branch.patch
warning: src/main/java/.../AbstractedPanel.java has type 100644, expected 100755
error: patch failed: src/main/java/.../AbstractedPanel.java:13
error: src/main/java/.../AbstractedPanel.java: patch does not apply
```

What does it mean?

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are there any AbstractedPanel.java.rej files lying around? Typical this means that a line bot changed in the source as well as in the patch (here line 13 seems to be affected).

Comment: No, I didn't find any *.rej files.

Comment: Have you tried reporting a bug to git@vger.kernel.org? None of the described options of Git apply work for me returning tons of errors. I had to fall back to WinMerge.

Comment: For me it meant I was git apply'ing a patch that was already in there FWIW...shame it doesn't give a more meaningful message...

Answer (score 407, accepted):

Johannes Sixt from the msysgit@googlegroups.com mailing list suggested using following command line arguments:

```
git apply --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace mychanges.patch
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: Can anyone help me and explain why this works? The other answer did not work for me, and I had the exact same problem as what the question asker describes. What do file attributes have to do with ignoring whitespace?

Comment: Using windows powershell A patch made with git diff was successfully applied as follows: git diff HEAD..613fee -- myfile.xml | git apply --ignore-space-change
 --ignore-whitespace, whereas first saving the diff output as a file did not work, in case anyone runs into the same problem

Comment: also try `-C1` switch for apply, it reduces the context around additions that are regarded as important.

Comment: @skrebbel: no doubt due to the line endings differing between the local file system and the remote repo.  Under some configurations Git will do magic with Windows-UNIX line ending translation (I advise against this).  Editors should be configured not to translate.  File attributes are probably not relevant.  There is the ".gitattributes" file, but this seems overkill for common scenarios.

Comment: @EricWalker, git magic with CR/LF isn't necessarily a bad thing. The alternative can be that half of your changesets consists of every single line in every file that was touched being changed from one line ending to the other, with the actual change buried somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @jwg I agree that huge changesets that only involve line endings is a problem. There are several ways to address this -- CR/LF conversion and configuring editors appropriately are two of them. Personally I like the editor option -- it feels cleaner to me, and contributors to a project should be on top of this detail. It's a preference rather than a rule.

Comment: @EricWalker But does 'appropriately' mean CR or CR/LF ? ;)

Comment: @jwg Ha!  I guess we all have our opinions there.  :)  More seriously, I think it depends upon the consensus of the project.  In this approach, you just decide on a standard line ending for the remote repo and live with it. It doesn't matter which one.

Comment: This helps sometimes. But other times, I still get the "patch does not apply", even though the patch should apply without issues.

Comment: Actually whitespaces are counts and they are part of the changeset! Ignoring them is just a workaround rather than a solution and ignoring them may not applicable in all cases. Today I hit a similar issue and explained the details here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62433613/199593

Comment: God. This is it. I'm so tired of working with patches.

Answer (score 696):

`git apply --reject --whitespace=fix mychanges.patch` worked for me.

### Explanation

The `--reject` option will instruct git to not fail if it cannot determine how to apply a patch, but instead to apply the individual hunks it can apply and create reject files (`.rej`) for hunks it cannot apply. [Wiggle](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wiggle) can "apply [these] rejected patches and perform word-wise diffs".

Additionally, `--whitespace=fix` will warn about whitespace errors and try to fix them, rather than refusing to apply an otherwise applicable hunk.

Both options together make the application of a patch more robust against failure, but they require additional attention with respect to the result.

For the whole documentation, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply.

Comment: This actually worked better for me because it didn't completely modify my file

Comment: This is great. Just rejects what it cannot solve itself and you can then just modify the rejected files manually.

Comment: patch -p1 <mychanges.patch # applies changes chunk by chunk. If changes fail a <sourcefile>.orig and <sourcefile>.rej patch are created and you can apply changes manually. I'm guessing git apply --reject does the same and --whitespace=fix is magically better.

Comment: this command creates `.rej` files when can't automatically detect how to apply a patch. You could use [wiggle](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wiggle) to resolve such issues.

Comment: This worked great for applying a patch created on Windows to a Git repo on a Mac (fixed the newline differences automatically).

Comment: This answer does not explain anything, in particular in which cases it will work. People, you really have to be more demanding of answer quality, this is SO not a forum.

Comment: Very Important: The `.rej` files are placed exactly near the file on which patch failed. They are visible in the `git status` and be sure to take care of them before commit

Comment: This, followed by `wiggle --replace file file.rej` and solving remaining conflicts in file (help by beautiful IDE support) fixed everything.
Thanks _a lot_, made my day :pray:

Comment: Live saver, would give you more points if I could.

Answer (score 272):

When all else fails, try [`git apply`'s `--3way` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#git-apply---3way).

`git apply --3way patchFile.patch`

> --3way
>   When the patch does not apply cleanly, fall back on 3-way merge if the
>   patch records the identity of blobs it is supposed to apply to, and we
>   have those blobs available locally, possibly leaving the conflict
>   markers in the files in the working tree for the user to resolve. This
>   option implies the --index option, and is incompatible with the
>   --reject and the --cached options.

Typical fail case applies as much of the patch as it can, and leaves you with conflicts to work out in git however you normally do so. Probably one step easier than the `reject` alternative.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. The file I was patching didn't reflect the changes that I generated the patch from (because I deleted the changes after I created the patch.)

Comment: Nice general solution. The 3way diff didn't look like it normally does so a little confused by that but never the less this gave me the ability to resolve the conflict and get the patch to apply.

Comment: I think this `--3way` should be the default behavior. When patching fails, at least tell me what failed so that I can manually fix it. `git apply` just fails and doesn't report why something fails. I couldn't even find `*.rej` files like the ones `hg` generates.

Comment: Definitely, the best solution. Let the user resolve his own conflicts!

Comment: Doesn't work for me in the case where the issues are caused by whitespace differences.  I never get a prompt, and `--3way` doesn't actually apply anything. ```error: patch failed: Foo.cs:4
Falling back to three-way merge...
error: patch failed: Foo.cs:4
error: Foo.cs: patch does not apply```However, on the same patch file, it will apply if I ignore whitespace (then I have to go fix  up the whitespace).

Comment: @Nathan Well, I did say "_When all else fails_" ;^D. But more usefully, if you'll put up the two files on paste.ee or something, I can certainly take a look. But I think you might be arguing for `git apply --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace --3way patchfile.patch` by identifying the people for whom [Mentiflectax's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4832785/1028230) works are in a wholly separate set than those whose problems are solved by this answer?

Comment: @ruffin Fair enough :-). Not necessarily arguing for any particular answer - I think many of the answers here apply in different situations.  I'm just a bit confused as to why `--3way` failed in the scenario I encountered.  I'd have to cleanup the files to remove confidential info before I could paste them, so I'll see if I can duplicate the issue with a non-confidential file.  (I have suspicions that there might be something different in the local git configs on different machines that's leading to the whitespace issue in the first place.)

Comment: `--3way` is way better than `--reject` as you end up with normal merge conflict that every git developer is used to resolve.

Comment: @PavanManjunath what's `hg`

Comment: @humbleCodes Command line app for a git alternative called [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/). It's kind of the betamax to git's VHS [[metaphor context here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Videotape_format_war#Competing_technologies)]. Actually [a few days younger than git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial#History).

Comment: @humbleCodes `hg` is another open source control management system. Just like `git`. https://www.mercurial-scm.org/

Answer (score 66):

This command will apply the patch not resolving it leaving bad files as `*.rej`:

```
git apply --reject --whitespace=fix mypath.patch
```

You just have to resolve them.  Once resolved run:

```
git -am resolved
```

Comment: how to resolve `*.rej` - all I can find is to make the changes manually in the source file & delete these `.rej` files. Any other way ?

Comment: @coding_idiot As usual, Just check the .rej files, compare them with the conflicting files and finally add the fixed files to the index (with "git add FIXED_FILES")

Comment: @coding_idiot you could use [wiggle](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wiggle) to resolve it. For example: `wiggle --replace path/to/file path/to/file.rej`. This command will apply changes from `.rej` file to original file. Also it creates a copy of original file, like `path/to/file.porig`. Please, checkout documentation to get more info about wiggle

Answer (score 43):

Try using the solution suggested here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1129120

`patch -p1 < example.patch`

This helped me .

Comment: I know you're not supposed to do this, but THANK YOU SO MUCH! Saved me hours.  I was getting "patch does not apply" and all sorts of errors.

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash, why are we not supposed to do this and why were you doing it nevertheless?

Comment: `git: 'patch' is not a git command.` on `git version 2.21.1 (Apple Git-122.3)`

Comment: @SridharSarnobat The command is `patch`, not `git patch`.See [patch(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/patch.1.html)

Comment: This is the way.   Forget `git patch`

Comment: If you are on **Windows** you probably don't have `patch` but you can open and apply the .patch in *TortoiseMerge* or whatever, the point is, use something that's not git!

Comment: sometime this works, sometime others answers works.

Answer (score 18):

It happens when you mix UNIX and Windows git clients because Windows doesn't really have the concept of the "x" bit so your checkout of a `rw-r--r--` (0644) file under Windows is "promoted" by the msys POSIX layer to be `rwx-r-xr-x` (0755).  git considers that mode difference to be basically the same as a textual difference in the file, so your patch does not directly apply.  I think your only good option here is to set `core.filemode` to `false` (using `git-config`).

Here's a msysgit issue with some related info:  [http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=164](https://web.archive.org/web/20131203192656/http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=164) (rerouted to archive.org's 3 Dec 2013 copy)

Comment: I tried to run the command "git config core.filemode false", but it didn't help - I'm still getting the same message.

Comment: Assuming you have no un-committed changes in your tree, try `git reset --hard HEAD` to force git to re-checkout your files with the new option in effect.

Comment: Just tried it out execute "git reset --hard HEAD". It was successful (I saw the message "HEAD is now at ..."), but the problem with "git apply" persists.

Answer (score 14):

Just use `git apply -v example.patch` to know the reasons of "patch does not apply". And then you can fix them one by one.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I was stupid enough to create the patch file incorrectly in the first place, actually *diff-ing the wrong way*. I ended up with the exact same error messages.

If you're on master and do `git diff branch-name > branch-name.patch`, this tries to remove all additions you want to happen and vice versa (which was impossible for git to accomplish since, obviously, never done additions cannot be removed).

So make sure you checkout to your branch and execute `git diff master > branch-name.patch`

Comment: I made the same mistake, look at chimurai answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65357332/1248565

Answer (score 6):

`git apply --reverse --reject example.patch`

When you created a patch file with the branch names reversed:

ie. `git diff feature_branch..master` instead of `git diff master..feature_branch`

Answer (score 1):

If the patch is only partly applied, but not the entire patch. Make sure you are in the correct directory when applying the patch.

For example I created a patch file in the parent project folder containing the `.git` file. However I was trying to apply the patch at a lower level. It was only applying changes at that level of the project.

Comment: This put me in the right direction. I was in the incorrect directory when applying the patch, because of which the patch was not applying. Thanks

Comment: @MShubat what do you mean by this - `I created a patch file in the parent project folder containing`

Comment: @DhruvSaraswat  how do you basically decide what is the correct directory to apply the patch ?

Answer (score 0):

My issue is that I ran `git diff`, then ran `git reset --hard HEAD`, then realized I wanted to undo, so I tried copying the output from `git diff` into a file and using `git apply`, but I got an error that "patch does not apply". After switching to `patch` and trying to use it, **I realized that a chunk of the diff was repeated for some reason, and after removing the duplicate**, `patch` (and presumably also `git apply`) worked.

Comment: @VirendraKumar I manually edited the diff file to remove the duplicate lines. I then used `patch`. (`git apply` would probably also work.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are:

1. Running the `git apply` command from the **root of the repository** (weird, but that was the only correct solution for me)
2. You are running `git apply` **without** `--check` option (in that case only the *check is executed*, but the patch itself is *not applied*)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

What I looked for is not exactly pointed out in here in SO, I'm writing for the benefit of others who might search for similar. I faced an issue with one file (present in old repo) getting removed in the repo. And when I apply the patch, it fails as it couldn't find the file to be applied. (so my case is git patch fails for file got removed)
'#git apply --reject' definitely gave a view but didn't quite get me to the fix. I couldn't use wiggle as it is not available for us in our build servers. In my case, I got through this problem by removing the entry of the 'file which got removed in the repo' from patch file I've tried applying, so I got all other changes applied without an issue (using 3 way merge, avoiding white space errors), And then manually merging content of file removed into where its moved.