# git newbie 2fer "your patch does not apply" error & option error

Tags: linux, git

First, since I'm a newbie at git, I'll have to post more background then may be necessary.
(I've edited this to remove all the path/file_names and search_for patterns)

```
# git apply -v patch_name.patch 
[...] trailing whitespace.
[...] trailing whitespace.
error: [...]
error: patch failed: ... :255
error: [...] : patch does not apply
[...]
```

I didn't find any 255 git errors, but I did find a promising one: [git: patch does not apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770177/git-patch-does-not-apply) Except this command produces error,

```
git apply --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace mychanges.patch
> error: unknown option `ignore-whitespace'
```

Same for the other --ignore-space-change option. A search at the [Git Wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools) could not find these commands. I'm using Linux/Fedora F11, a few years old, but I'm a newbie and not going for linux certification :). What is the equivalent command for Linux/Fedora?

PS. Yes, just what I was thinking. Git is slang for idiot, which is synonymous for newbie

**UPDATE** Below is the new message from git. Is this half fixed?

```
file_name.patch:26: trailing whitespace.
file_name.patch:39: trailing whitespace.
Checking patch file_name...
Hunk #1 succeeded at 294 (offset 6 lines).
Checking patch file_name.inc...
Hunk #1 succeeded at 23 (offset -1 lines).
Checking patch [...] 
Hunk #1 succeeded at 79 (offset 12 lines).
error: while searching for:
[...]
error: patch failed: file_name:255
error: file_name: patch does not apply
Checking patch file_name...
Hunk #1 succeeded at 17 (offset 4 lines).
```

Comment: I very much wish to discover if I can make this patch work...

Answer (score 0):

What do you get from `git --version`? `--ignore-whitespace` was added in version 1.6.5. Assuming you have an older version and don't want to upgrade, maybe `--whitespace=fix` would help?

Comment: Oi! Why does everyone say I don't "want" to upgrade when your software is not cooperating? FFt! I tried "yum install python-software-properties" supposed to update git clone, and "yum update git" and one other. Its not working. I'm version 1.6.2 :(

Comment: --whitespace=fix didn't take. No option error, but the output was the same as the first error above...

Comment: UPDATE- I managed to make/confing an update to 1.7 despite instructions requiring libexpat1-dev and libssl-dev which I can't find for Fedora 11 (I did install somefin called expat1, and no luck with ssl). The --ignore-* options work...