# Repair Missing Tree

Tags: git

My git repo has become corrupted and unfortunately it only exists locally.

```
$ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
broken link from    tree 54b4ff576b2e39831a298e58a38d91890f622b63
              to    tree d564d0bc3dd917926892c55e3706cc116d5b165e
missing tree d564d0bc3dd917926892c55e3706cc116d5b165e
```

I checked into what `d564d0bc` is, and it is my `log/` folder in a rails project. This folder only contains `*.log` files (which are ignored) and a `.gitkeep` file.

I tried following the steps mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236738/how-can-i-recover-my-git-repository-for-a-missing-tree-error), but I'm using GitHub for Windows and powershell is screaming at me over an empty pipe.

Any help is appreciated.

Update: I copied the project into linux so I wouldn't have to worry about powershell commands. I still haven't found a solution though.

Comment: +1 for realizing to move to a proper shell

Comment: What command did you use to '... check into what d564d0bc is' ?

Comment: @EoghanM Sorry, checked in was confusing. I looked into what it was. It's been a long time but I think it was probably just a `git checkout d564d0bc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that missing tree contained only .gitkeep file and you have its content than it is possible to recreate missing tree.

All you need to know is a bunch of low-level git commands? Are you ready? Go!
The first of all. You need to use `git mktree`.

This command reads from stdin data and creates a tree based on this information. It outputs the sha1 summ of newly created tree (**Don't forget** to check that it equals to d564d0bc3dd917926892c55e3706cc116d5b165e)

Next thing you need to know what the format of this input?!
The format is the following

```
<mode> SP <type> SP <object> TAB <file>
```

where SP is a space, TAB is a tab.

- is a file mode
- is a git object type (blob for files, tree for folders)
- is a sha1 hash of the object
- is a file name

Let me show an example.
To create the tree from this folder (the some_file file is empty)

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 aleksandr aleksandr 4096 2012-07-25 03:51 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 aleksandr aleksandr 4096 2012-07-25 03:54 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 aleksandr aleksandr    0 2012-07-25 03:51 some_file
```

you need to run

```
echo -e "100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391\tsome_file" | git mktree
```

But how did you find out the desired sha1 hash?! `git hash-object` to the rescue.
Just

```
git hash-object log/.gitkeep
```

to determine its hash. I think that all you need to know to repair your repository.

Comment: Thank you so much. For anyone else that might have this problem, you need to `cd` into the folder, you can't just use a path. In my example I had to go into my `log` folder.

The final command I used is:
`echo -e "100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391\t.gitkeep" | git mktree`