# Egit in eclipse missing tree

Tags: eclipse, git

Looks like I have a missing tree error. Just to be fair, I did totally just mess up my local files on git and got fed up and did a complete hard disk delete on my repo and recloned from remote master. Now I'm getting the following error. One of the first things I did was create a local branch for my work.

Chances are I could've recovered a lot of my work if I didn't delete everything but hey, pass tense - right? (This may show my state of my mind right now with git and my project too...)

If it makes any difference I am making an android project.

I'm reading  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638844/repair-missing-tree) post and it seems helpful but I have no idea how to find my "a30df1173f14dea24df661f1eef749fed2f4e1ed" sha1 hash.

Doing

> git ls-tree a30df1173f14dea24df661f1eef749fed2f4e1ed

Gives me the following

```
100755 blob 2851ba4fdf2a134f8fc97fd60b3045b73cd6039b    .DS_Store
100755 blob 3f9691c5dda29b09cb96060fd6ec7017f6c671d2    .classpath
100755 blob c50d3b4fe2f6221db617840561dc94d7690bb883    .gitignore
100755 blob 6b58f1723a252cfd314d108fadac4b71a4209c1c    .project
100755 blob 39f00018845d776de324707090d26c5153720e22    AndroidManifest.xml
100755 blob 94a9ed024d3859793618152ea559a168bbcbb5e2    COPYING
100755 blob c1853e4c312a938d5890f5f4e0844782429ba11e    default.properties
040000 tree 423accda532f8788f916b26b863ddf32e2896aa6    docs
160000 commit 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  eagle vision
100755 blob 424f2604203eabd2310165b143b430326aa87ee7    ic_launcher-web.png
040000 tree 2b83cd828cd11a11e84a2d8f646dfa40de109827    libs
100644 blob 8a7b1fac8f8c12e925e56776f225730c4712f92a    lint.xml
040000 tree c0182f719fccf5fc8b0d7658c3d15fe4deac0d9e    plugins
100755 blob f2fe1559a217865a5454add526dcc446f892385b    proguard-project.txt
100755 blob 9ae01de96458dbded45d2a442c09c0f4d33e473a    project.properties
040000 tree 3c9446b3bb23eebe80942992ee03e01a7390ba80    res
040000 tree 895e957ccc4ee642127c25a3481d784302e44a70    src
```

Out of all of them the eagle vision seems weird with all those 0's:

> 160000 commit 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  eagle vision

Not really sure where I'm going with this though. Trying to go through the git faq doesn't go very far.

Here's the whole error:

```
eclipse.buildId=v22.0.0-675183
java.version=1.7.0_21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

Error
Sun Oct 13 21:11:59 CDT 2013
Missing tree 2ec4e5b3e0e3d9ccc766fd1ed0dccaedcef3e53a

org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing tree 2ec4e5b3e0e3d9ccc766fd1ed0dccaedcef3e53a
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.CanonicalTreeParser.reset(CanonicalTreeParser.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.parserFor(TreeWalk.java:984)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.addTree(TreeWalk.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.synchronize.GitSyncCache.loadDataFromGit(GitSyncCache.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.synchronize.GitSyncCache.getAllData(GitSyncCache.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.synchronize.GitSyncCache.getAllData(GitSyncCache.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.synchronize.GitResourceVariantTreeSubscriber.refresh(GitResourceVariantTreeSubscriber.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.team.core.subscribers.Subscriber.refresh(Subscriber.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.synchronize.GitSubscriberMergeContext.handleRepositoryChange(GitSubscriberMergeContext.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.synchronize.GitSubscriberMergeContext.access$0(GitSubscriberMergeContext.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.synchronize.GitSubscriberMergeContext$1.indexDiffChanged(GitSubscriberMergeContext.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.indexdiff.IndexDiffCache.notifyListeners(IndexDiffCache.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.indexdiff.IndexDiffCache.access$0(IndexDiffCache.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.indexdiff.IndexDiffCache$1.indexDiffChanged(IndexDiffCache.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.indexdiff.IndexDiffCacheEntry.notifyListeners(IndexDiffCacheEntry.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.indexdiff.IndexDiffCacheEntry.access$8(IndexDiffCacheEntry.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.indexdiff.IndexDiffCacheEntry$5.run(IndexDiffCacheEntry.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`160000` is a [special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309) for recording a submodule.
A SHA1 equals to 40 zeros means the submodule has been deleted (see [`git-submodule.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-submodule.sh#L1050-L1069)) or in an [unknown state](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/75663):

> When you compare something with a work tree state, and when the work tree state is dirty, we always show `0{40}` to mean "it is dirty and we do not know what the object name of that thing is, until you actuallly run git-update-index (or git-add) it" (and at that point it would stop being dirty).
>   For blobs (be it a regular file or a symbolic link), this has an advantage of not having to run hash-object to obtain the object name of an object that would be created if you actually did git-add it.
>
> When we check if it is dirty, we already do an lstat(2) and know the type
>   of it, so we can show the mode bits.  So you will see 100644, 100755 or
>   120000 for blobs.  Similarly for a submodule.
>
> For a submodule, we could read the value from $sub/.git/HEAD, but it is more consistent to show 0{40} on the work tree side (typically the right hand side, unless you use -R).

So check if you have a `.git/modules/asubmodule/HEAD`.
Or try to [cleanup your submodule entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309), and then redeclare that submodule to eagle-vision url.

But your missing tree might not be related to that entry though.

Comment: I followed the link to cleanup a submodule entry - but I don't even get

Comment: @xphill64x can you try a `git rm eagle vision`?

Comment: git rm 'eagle vision' did not match any files.

Comment: @xphill64x `git rm --cached 'eagle vision'` then?

Comment: Still not found. I'm getting an additional error in git fsck about a bad email in another commit. I've found the offending tag [extra <] but I have no idea how to edit the commit; suggestions?