# Git Repository Corruption -- missing tree

Tags: git

I've been using git with a personal project in Eclipse for 7 years now.  I experienced hard drive issues with my old machine, and I copied a backup to my new machine, but I get an error when I try to look at the history for all of the files under a particular source folder (unfortunately, my main one).

Cannot compute Git history.
Missing tree 714a885cc890d7557277451737c1c2b9547525d8

```
git fsck says similar things:
error: object file .git/objects/af/b1a2fad4670ee56f1d0984c03f926fc248bf09 is empty
error: unable to mmap .git/objects/af/b1a2fad4670ee56f1d0984c03f926fc248bf09: No such file or directory
error: afb1a2fad4670ee56f1d0984c03f926fc248bf09: object corrupt or missing: .git/objects/af/b1a2fad4670ee56f1d0984c03f926fc248bf09
error: object file .git/objects/cd/d1df5c08ff1e8fbacf96e50a7b2580b153c510 is empty
error: unable to mmap .git/objects/cd/d1df5c08ff1e8fbacf96e50a7b2580b153c510: No such file or directory
error: cdd1df5c08ff1e8fbacf96e50a7b2580b153c510: object corrupt or missing: .git/objects/cd/d1df5c08ff1e8fbacf96e50a7b2580b153c510
broken link from    tree e1de2d91314381db3dcebf6d2143742a60fe5d68
              to    tree 714a885cc890d7557277451737c1c2b9547525d8
dangling commit 1400e1f4af9dabc5b089b72ddc9258219e92d139
...
```

But when I look at the project with gitk, I see all 1500+ commits, and everything looks OK there, which gives me hope that there may be an easy (relatively) way to rebuild the trees.  I'd hate to lose the history for my project.

I tried cloning the repository, but the clone has the same issue.  "git gc" also failed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I recover my Git repository for a "missing tree" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236738/how-can-i-recover-my-git-repository-for-a-missing-tree-error)

Comment: @j08691 I don't think that's a good question to point the OP to. That's a different "missing tree" error with a different cause and a different solution. There is no de-synced remote repo here, just a partially corrupt local repo. Telling the OP to nuke dangling object on what may be their only copy of the repo has a high risk of data loss.

Comment: "I see all 1500+ commits" have you verified you see the commits git is saying are missing?

Comment: re: _"git gc" also failed."_ Be careful running `git gc`, and be sure to make a backup of the repo first. Running `git gc` is essentially the only way that objects gets permanently deleted from a git repo. Note that "tree" object is basically a record of what states of what files belong to a commit. If you're _missing_ a tree, then some historic states of files could appear to be "dangling" to git. "Successfully" running some `git gc` commands could could permanently delete historic versions of files.

Comment: these days github, if not competitors, supports private repos for free, so there's really no good reason not to have a copy of your repo pushed somewhere other than your local machine.  I know this doesn't help you now, but for next time!

Comment: Brian61354270, I tried "git gc" on a copy of the repository, not the original.

Comment: Erik258, I didn't think about that.  I suppose there may have been 2000+ commits, and I only see 70% of them.  fsck does report 700+ dangling commits.  At this point I'm thinking of starting with a fresh repository, so even if I can get most of the history back, I'll be happy.  I'll definitely look ino your repo push suggestion.