# 'git apply' failed with code 1: trailing whitespace in SourceTree

Tags: git, line-endings, core.autocrlf

I'm using [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) for easy code reviewing before committing. Within SourceTree I often stage and commit only part of the lines which I changed in a document.

A couple days ago I received a piece of code from a programmer working on Windows, which caused some trouble with line endings. If I remember correctly, I then set `core.autocrlf` to `true`, which fixed the issues with the windows file. 
Since that moment however, I'm having major issues in another repo I'm working on. If I want to stage only part of a file in SourceTree I now get a massive error saying `git apply' failed with code 1: [/a/long/path/here] trailing whitespace in SourceTree`. So I figured I needed to set `core.autocrlf` back to what it was, which I "assumed" to be ("mother of all.. etc") `false` (I never messed with `core.autocrlf` before). So I set it to `false` which suddenly makes all files on which I change only one letter to be marked as having changed ALL lines in the file, which is obviously a major hassle during code review.

So I searched around and I found some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649605/git-apply-fails-mysteriously-how-do-i-troubleshoot-fix) of [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591923/make-git-automatically-remove-trailing-whitespace-before-committing) here on SO, but that all uses adding extra parameters to `git add` and doing all kinds of weird stuff. Next to the fact that I don't think I can insert custom commands in the GUI of SourceTree I mostly wondered; How did it get so messy? And most importantly can't I just go back to how it was (whatever that was) instead of having to issue extra command everytime that I want to stage and commit?

Please note; I'm not afraid of the command line, I work in it pretty much the whole day. But I just like doing code reviews in a GUI such as SourceTree.

Any tip which helps me get things back to normal would greatly help me out!

Answer (score 18):

Set "Ignore whitespace".  See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I would have preferred to just add this as a comment to @Mykola's answer, but it doesn't appear you can add images in comments :(.

Comment: I was having OP's problem, but had already set Sourcetree's diff settings to "Ignore whitespace." Toggling to "show whitespace" fixed the issue for me.

Comment: this works on Sourcetree v4.1.5 (2021)

Comment: @LeeRichardson you can edit other peoples answers however

Answer (score 11):

There is a [discussion](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Partial-stage-unstage-operations-fail-with-cryptic-error/qaq-p/426356) on Atlassian Community about this problem. The fix is to switch setting Show Whitespace to Ignore Whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

In your ~/.gitconfig, try adding the following section:

```
[apply]
    whitespace = nowarn
```

The full details of what this does are covered at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply

The options for apply.whitespace are (from the git-scm page):

- "nowarn" turns off the trailing whitespace warning.
- "warn" outputs warnings for a few such errors, but applies the patch as-is (default).
- "fix" outputs warnings for a few such errors, and applies the patch after fixing them
- "error" outputs warnings for a few such errors, and refuses to apply the patch.
- "error-all" is similar to error but shows all errors.

Seems like the default for SourceTree under OS X is "error", at least with git 2.6.4.  Or it may be interacting with our default of `core.autocrlf = true`

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, for me the solution was to do the exact opposite to the [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48769641/4298200), which was to switch from "Ignore Whitespace" to "Show Whitespace" as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45018345/4298200).