# 'git apply' failed with code 1: patch does not apply error in SourceTree on Stage Hunk

Tags: git, macos, virtual-machine, atlassian-sourcetree, parallels

When I attempt to stage a hunk or some lines, I get the following error in SourceTree on OS X:

[image: git apply failed with code 1 patch failed]

Staging entire files works fine. The path of this repo lives on a Windows virtual machine running in Parallels.

I suspect a whitespace or newline issue. How do I make this work without reverting to hg-git?

Comment: same here. Arrives 'from time to time' without a rule. OSX 10.12.5 with Xcode 8.3

Answer (score 5):

I changed the setting back to 'Show Whitespace' and things seem better.

Comment: Actually, the fix for me was the opposite: setting it to '_Ignore whitespace_' would solve the patching issue.

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue for me, neither option.

Comment: This fixed it for me today. 4 years after both the question and answer... Great job Atlassian