# SourceTree git apply failed with code 1 - File does not exist in index

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using SourceTree as git GUI client.

Today I've pulled a commit from the repo, but I've got a warning message because one of the files contains a conflict with the same file in my local repository.

I've tried to resolve the conflict manually, by selecting the lines I want to keep and then I've clicked `Stage lines`, but I've got this error message:

[image: Error message]

The content of `LastFailedPatch.txt` is:

```
diff --git a/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml b/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
--- a/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml   
+++ b/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml   
@@ -49,5 +49,11 @@
         <item quantity="many">Certifications</item>
     </plurals>
     <string name="title_activity_chat">ChatActivity</string>
+
+    <!-- Intent bundle keys -->
+
+    <string name="intent_key_user">User</string>
+
+
     <string name="title_activity_chat_menu">ChatMenuActivity</string>
 </resources>
```

I've tried to select `Ignore whitespace` option in SourceTree, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was resolved once I set the option back to "Show whitespace" as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45018345/4298200).

Though it seems to be the solution only for a small group of people.

I am using Sourcetree on Windows.