# Flutter Error : Getter not found : 'iMobileDevice' when trying to rebuild Flutter tool

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter, libimobiledevice

Good afternoon,

I am following the tutorial on Windows 7 for an Ipad on IOS 9.3.5 :

https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667
 and I'm stuck at **rebuilding the Flutter Tool**. (Last part of the tutorial)

I downloaded (from the link of the tutorial) and copied in `C:\src\flutter\bin`  the **libimobiledevice**, **ideviceinstaller** and **which** binaries.
Then I ran the `git apply ios.diff` which gives me multiple errors, sometimes it's just about mac.dart, and sometimes it's more like this :

```
error: patch failed: packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/devices.dart:103
error: packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/devices.dart: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/ios_workflow.dart:26
error: packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/ios_workflow.dart: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/mac.dart:124
error: packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/mac.dart: patch does not apply
```

Then I found this command in here : [git: patch does not apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770177/git-patch-does-not-apply)

```
git apply --reject --whitespace=fix mychanges.patch
```

What I got was : (don't mind the content of the `Future<String>`, it's because I've already changed it to what it was supposed to be)

```
Checking patch packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/mac.dart...
error: while searching for:
  Future<String> getAvailableDeviceIDs() async {
    try {
      final ProcessResult result = await processManager.run(<String>['idevice_id', '-l']);
      if (result.exitCode != 0)
        throw ToolExit('idevice_id returned an error:\n${result.stderr}');
      return result.stdout;
    } on ProcessException {
      throw ToolExit('Failed to invoke idevice_id. Run flutter doctor.');

error: patch failed: packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/mac.dart:124
Applying patch packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/devices.dart with 1 reject...
Rejected hunk #1.
Applying patch packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/ios_workflow.dart with 1 reject...
Rejected hunk #1.
Applying patch packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/mac.dart with 1 reject...
Rejected hunk #1.
```

At this point I manually pasted the right content in the **mac.dart** file (as you might have seen in the error above), but I am still not sure everything went well because of the :

```
error: patch failed: packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/mac.dart:124
```

Anyway, I kept going and ran the command to rebuild the flutter tool:

```
bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart --snapshot=.\bin\cache\flutter_tools.snapshot --packages=.\packages\flutter_tools\.packages .\packages\flutter_tools\bin\flutter_tools.dart
```

Finally, the output is this :

```
C:\src\flutter>bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart --snapshot=.\bin\cache\flutter_tools.snapshot --packages=.\packages\flutter_tools\.packages .\
packages\flutter_tools\bin\flutter_tools.dart
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/ios_workflow.dart:20:30: Error: Getter not found: 'iMobileDevice'.
  bool get canListDevices => iMobileDevice.isInstalled || (xcode.isInstalledAndMeetsVersionCheck && xcode.isSimctlInstalled);
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/ios_workflow.dart:20:30: Error: The getter 'iMobileDevice' isn't defined for the class 'IOSWorkflow'.
 - 'IOSWorkflow' is from 'package:flutter_tools/src/ios/ios_workflow.dart' ('packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/ios_workflow.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'iMobileDevice'.
  bool get canListDevices => iMobileDevice.isInstalled || (xcode.isInstalledAndMeetsVersionCheck && xcode.isSimctlInstalled);
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is this "iMobileDevice" related to this libimobiledevice ? I can run any of the `ideviceinstaller.exe` or `idevice_id.exe`, so I guess I installed it correctly.

I am missing something important to correct this error ?

Thanks a lot for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot ! Importing 'mac.dart' allowed me to apply everything correctly.

I then ran `flutter attach`, and here is what I get : (I guess only the first lines are useful)

```
D:\Beerproject>flutter attach

Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: 5d71ca5958062efd)
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.

Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: 5024a42feb468e2b)
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Unhandled exception:
Unsupported operation: Control of iOS devices or simulators only supported on Mac OS.
#0      IOSDevice.getAttachedDevices (package:flutter_tools/src/ios/devices.dart:172:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      IOSDevices.pollingGetDevices (package:flutter_tools/src/ios/devices.dart:117:57)
#2      PollingDeviceDiscovery.devices (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:270:52)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      DeviceManager.getAllConnectedDevices (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:136:46)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      DeviceValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:760:54)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      Doctor.startValidatorTasks (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:140:52)
#6      Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:211:41)
#7      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:43:6)
#8      Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:201:24)
#9      _doctorText.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:202:26)
#10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:154:29)
#11     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:43:6)
#12     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:154:7)
#13     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#14     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#15     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#16     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#17     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:18)
#18     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:43:6)
#19     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:140:19)
#20     _doctorText (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:201:19)
#21     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:43:6)
#22     _doctorText (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:197:27)
#23     _createLocalCrashReport (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:179:32)
#24     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:43:6)
#25     _createLocalCrashReport (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:164:37)
#26     _handleToolError (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:134:33)
#27     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#28     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#29     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#30     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#31     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#32     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#33     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#34     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:30:15)
#35     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:288:13)
#36     CrashReportSender.sendReport (package:flutter_tools/src/reporting/crash_reporting.dart)
#37     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#38     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#39     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#40     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#41     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#42     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#43     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:512:7)
#44     Stream.fold.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream.dart:801:18)
#45     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
#46     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#47     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#48     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:389:13)
#49     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399:15)
#50     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:283:7)
#51     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:96:11)
#52     _EventSinkWrapper.close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:23:11)
#53     _StringAdapterSink.close (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:249:11)
#54     _Utf8ConversionSink.close (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:300:20)
#55     _ConverterStreamEventSink.close (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:80:18)
#56     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:141:24)
#57     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
#58     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#59     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#60     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:389:13)
#61     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399:15)
#62     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:283:7)
#63     _ForwardingStream._handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:106:10)
#64     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:172:13)
#65     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
#66     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#67     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#68     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:389:13)
#69     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399:15)
#70     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:283:7)
#71     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:96:11)
#72     _EventSinkWrapper.close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:23:11)
#73     _Uint8ListConversionSink.close (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:577:13)
#74     _ConverterStreamEventSink.close (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:80:18)
#75     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:141:24)
#76     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
#77     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#78     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#79     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:389:13)
#80     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399:15)
#81     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:283:7)
#82     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:96:11)
#83     _EventSinkWrapper.close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:23:11)
#84     _ByteAdapterSink.close (dart:convert/byte_conversion.dart:62:11)
#85     _FilterSink.close (dart:io/data_transformer.dart:637:11)
#86     _ConverterStreamEventSink.close (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:80:18)
#87     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:141:24)
#88     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
#89     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#90     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#91     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:389:13)
#92     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399:15)
#93     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:283:7)
#94     _ForwardingStream._handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:106:10)
#95     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:172:13)
#96     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
#97     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#98     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#99     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:389:13)
#100    _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399:15)
#101    _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:283:7)
#102    _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendDone (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:772:19)
#103    _StreamController._closeUnchecked (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:629:7)
#104    _StreamController.close (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:622:5)
#105    _HttpParser._closeIncoming (dart:_http/http_parser.dart:1037:23)
#106    _HttpParser._doParse (dart:_http/http_parser.dart:752:11)
#107    _HttpParser._parse (dart:_http/http_parser.dart:318:7)
#108    _HttpParser._onData (dart:_http/http_parser.dart:810:5)
#109    _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#110    _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#111    _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
#112    _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#113    _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#114    _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:764:19)
#115    _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:640:7)
#116    _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:586:5)
#117    _Socket._onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1791:41)
#118    _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#119    _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#120    _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
#121    _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#122    _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#123    _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:764:19)
#124    _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:640:7)
#125    _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:586:5)
#126    _RawSecureSocket._sendReadEvent (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:1004:19)
#127    _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
#128    _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#129    _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#130    _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
#131    _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#132    _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#133    _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#134    Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:21:15)
#135    _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
#136    _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
#137    _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

Did anyone ever got this error ?

EDIT : following this tutorial step by step didn't solve the problem ... (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkWPQHLOAEw)

SOLVED : I finally ended up using the Mac of a friend. Maybe could work using a virtual machine as well.

Answer (score 1):

in the "ios_workflow.dart" file you have to write this where the other 'import...' rows are:

import 'mac.dart';

For me, it's solved the problem.