# git: move stash to repository in another directory

Tags: git, git-stash

I have a local stash on a directory.

For some reasons, I had to re-import the same remote project into another directory.

Is there a way to move my stash from my old directory to the new created one since they follow the same remote project and branches ?

Comment: You can create a patch, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3973058/2082964

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export a stash to another computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973034/export-a-stash-to-another-computer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to copy the .git directory from the old repo over the new one. Git stores every object in files within that directory so that should return your stash.

Comment: it might be a way to fix this issue, but I would suggest try the other way in comment by @Chris Maes

Comment: Oh, yes, it seems to be a cleaner way to fix the issue

Comment: This answer is excessive. Usually one clones a new instance of repo because of problems/inconsistencies in the old and doesn't want to drag `.git` on for this very reason (but only the stash for example).

Comment: @Magnas would be cool if you can change the accepted answer to not confuse future travellers.

Answer (score 19):

The steps mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/alexeds/3641372) were helpful for me when I faced this same situation which the OP faced. Copy-pasting the steps below, in case the link doesn't work -

In your old repository/directory -

```
git stash show -p > patchfile
```

If you have a specific stash you wish to migrate -

```
git stash show -p stash@{5} > patchfile
```

In your new repository/directory (make sure you're in the correct directory, or you might face errors while applying the patch) -

```
git apply /old/project/dir/patchfile
git stash
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`git stash branch`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) to create a branch from your stash:

`$ git stash branch <branchname> [<stash>]`

This command performs the following:

- Creates a new branch with `<branchname>`
- Switches you to the new branch
- Applies the specified stash (or the latest stash if omitted)
- Stages all stashed changes for commit

After you commit and push the changes on this branch, you can then fetch or pull from it.

Answer (score 0):

If stash is hard for you, you should push your change to the remote branch and then check out it from the new repository, everything still keeps the same

Answer (score 0):

After searching and not finding any simple solutions to copy all of my stashes and branches to a new clone of a Git repo, I went ahead and created one myself in the form of a shell script. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/jwarkentin/0cd53beda345afde53cf1464237f7f32) with the script. Grab the file and be sure to run `chmod u+x migrate-git-repo.sh` in the directory where you save it. Then just use it like this:

```bash
./migrate-git-repo.sh <path-to-old-repo> <path-to-new-clone>
```

Relative paths are fine. It prompts along the way in case you only want to copy stashes and not branches. It will protect against unclean work trees. Feedback is welcome. Hopefully this makes someone else's life easier.