# how to do an export for git stash

Tags: git

I want to export one stash (the changes) that I see in my stash list in a `.zip/.gz` file. I have found the following command:

```
git stash show -p > patch
```

which saves the changes in a file, but I also want to keep `.png` files, etc... I am looking for a way to compress **all** of the changes contained in the stash in a file or a folder. Do you know any solution ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export a stash to another computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973034/export-a-stash-to-another-computer)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try it with `--binary` option to export

```
git stash show -p --binary > changes.patch
```

When you want to import it, apply the patch

```
git apply changes.patch
```

Answer (score 9):

While Samual Robert's answer does solve the stated problem, something to note:

`git stash show` will combine all staged and unstaged changes into a single patch, and will exclude untracked files even if you used `git stash -u`.  By default `git apply` will make all of the changes in the patch into unstaged changes; you can make them staged by giving the `--index` option.  But to preserve the distinction between staged and unstaged changes, or to include untracked files that are in the stash, you need to do something else.

A stash internally consists of two or three commits and some ref manipulation, so one option is to generate a patch from each commit and then reconstruct the stash manually on the other end.  It takes a little trickery to get the right patches because of the way the commits are related.

```
git show stash^2 --binary >index.patch
git show stash^3 --binary >untracked.patch
git diff --binary stash^2 stash >wip.patch
```

Then on the receiving end

```
git apply index.patch
git add .
git apply wip.patch
git apply untracked.patch
```

Now the uncommitted state has been recreated on the other repo, and if you want you could re-stash it there.

If you need to materialize the change on the receiving end directly as a stash, without going through your worktree and index -- e.g. because the receiving side isn't in a "clean" state - you could do it using bundles.  But there is a trick to making this work.  On the source repo

```
git bundle create stash.bundle stash^..stash
```

On the receiving repo

```
git remote add bundle stash.bundle
git fetch stash:temp
git update-ref --create-reflog refs/stash temp
git branch -D temp
```

Note that we had to give an explicit refspec to get the `stash` ref out of the bundle.  If we'd mapped it directly to refs/stash, then we can't count on a reflog entry being created - and without the reflog entry, it's not a usable stash.  So instead we brought it in to a temporary branch, then used `update-ref` to create (or move) the `stash` ref and update the reflog.

Answer (score 1):

**This approach ensures a smooth transfer of work between computers while maintaining the version history.**

The trick is that we **commit** the changes, **push** to remote, **pull** on destincation, **create a patch from commit**, and then **revert** the commit.
from there we **apply the patch** that contains our changes.

---

Remember to **replace your_branch_name** with actual BRANCH name.

---

> Step 1: Commit Changes on Source Computer:

```
git add .
git commit -m "WIP"
```

> Step 2: Push Changes to Remote:

```
git push origin your_branch_name
```

> Step 3: Pull Changes on Destination Computer:

```
git pull origin your_branch_name
```

> Step 4: Create a Patch from last commit that just pulled:

```
git checkout your_branch_name
git format-patch HEAD^ -o .
git add .
git stash save "Patch"
```

> Step 5: Revert the WIP Commit:

```
git reset HEAD^
git add .
git commit -m "revert WIP"
```

> Step 6: Pop Stash and Apply Patch:

```
git stash pop
git apply --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace  0001-wip.patch
```

This sequence of commands allows you to export changes from one computer to another using Git's version control features. It involves committing, pushing, pulling, generating a patch, stashing, reverting, and applying the changes.