# How to share a "Git Stash" in Visual Studio / AzureDevOps?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2022, git-stash

How can you share Stashes in VS2022?

[image]

I know this can be done with Git: [Export a stash to another computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973034/export-a-stash-to-another-computer).

I've done research and can't find anyway with VS2022 or AzureDevOps and am hoping for CLI command or a 3rd party tool like the old TFS Sidekicks? I'm not sure its possible *yet*, even a solution with VS Code is acceptable.

<sub>The issue is our Common Libraries are Azure Artefacts and to debug we need to switch solutions to reference Projects. A Stash is perfect but can't be shared.</sub>

Comment: Why not push a branch with the changes?

Comment: I don't want to be telling people "First checkout the debug branch for xyz.SubSolution, stash those changes, then create a New Branch from Dev trunk (not the debug branch) and do your coding changes there, then revert the stash and check it works and merge back". Much prefer the process is simpler: "Get latest, New Branch, do your coding changes and if you need to debug/Edit & Continue then apply the "debug stash" and revert it before checking in".

Comment: The benefit of a branch is that it would be present in everyone's repos.  The stash is basically a patch you can apply or revert, so from a well-known remote branch you could give directions to generate, apply, and revert the patch.  It could also evolve over time without having to change the instructions (updated via fetch).

Comment: Ok, that seems feasible. "Checkout the Debug Branch and Stash those changes, if you ever need to debug apply the Stashes Debug diff's."