# How to Git stash pop specific stash in 1.8.3?

Tags: git, escaping, git-stash

I just upgraded Git. I'm on Git version 1.8.3.

This morning I tried to unstash a change 1 deep in the stack.

I ran `git stash pop stash@{1}` and got this error.

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'stash@1': unknown revision or path not in
>   the working tree.
>       Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>       'git  [...] -- [...]'

I've tried about 20+ variations on this as well as using `apply` instead of `pop` with no success. What's changed? Anyone else encounter this?

Comment: Did you try escaping the {}'s?

Comment: With Git 2.11 (Q4 2016), you can now use `git stash pop 1`: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40543440/6309)

Answer (score 741, accepted):

```
git stash apply n
```

works as of git version 2.11

Original answer, possibly helping to debug issues with the older syntax involving shell escapes:

As pointed out previously, the curly braces may require escaping or quoting depending on your OS, shell, etc.

See "[stash@{1} is ambiguous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468893/stash1-is-ambiguous)" for some detailed hints of what may be going wrong, and how to work around it in various shells and platforms.

```
git stash list
git stash apply stash@{n}
```

[git stash apply version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910082/git-stash-apply-version/1910142#1910142)

Comment: My only nit with this answer is that the question asks how to `pop` a specific stash and this command `apply`s the stash rather than popping it. The difference being that a pop both applies the stash to the code and deletes the stash itself.

Comment: Not working for me. 
Getting error "unknown option: -encodedCommand"

Comment: [Since the version 2.11 you can type:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910082/git-stash-apply-version/44451133#44451133) 
`git stash apply n`

Comment: Also, you can type `git stash pop '<stash-ref>'` where stash-ref is like `stash{0}`. Don't forget the quotes

Comment: This also works for commands like `git stash show 1`, which will do `git stash show` with the *second* item on the stash stack

Answer (score 240):

You need to escape the braces:

```
git stash pop stash@\{1\}
```

Comment: or just put into doubles quote, e.g. git stash pop "stash@{1}"

Answer (score 156):

If you want to be sure to *not* have to deal with quotes for the syntax `stash@{x}`, use Git 2.11 (Q4 2016)

See [commit a56c8f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a56c8f5aab5a6ffdd687de5134883df60cc4c919) (24 Oct 2016) by [Aaron M Watson (`watsona4`)](https://github.com/watsona4).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9fa1f90](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9fa1f902bf8eaaa2a1d78cd7603d28a33d46e30c), 31 Oct 2016)</sup>

> ### `stash`: allow stashes to be referenced by index only
>
> Instead of referencing "`stash@{n}`" explicitly, make it possible to
>   simply reference as "`n`".
>   Most users only reference stashes by their position in the stash stack (what I refer to as the "index" here).
>
> The syntax for the typical stash (`stash@{n}`) is slightly annoying and
>   easy to forget, **and sometimes difficult to escape properly in a
>   script**.
>
> Because of this the capability to do things with the stash by
>   simply referencing the index is desirable.

So:

```
git stash drop 1
git stash pop 1
git stash apply 1
git stash show 1
```

Answer (score 81):

#### Update

From git 2.11 just use the number:

```
git stash apply 1
```

#### Orginal

On Windows Powershell I run this:

```
git stash apply "stash@{1}"
```

Comment: Works on ubuntu linux too

Comment: also works on Mac OS X. I like this better than escaping single characters.

Answer (score 19):

As Robert pointed out, quotation marks might do the trick for you:

```
git stash pop stash@"{1}"
```

Answer (score 16):

If none of the above work, quotation marks around the stash itself might work for you:

```
git stash pop "stash@{0}"
```

Answer (score 15):

I have 2.22 installed and this worked..

```
git stash pop --index 1
```

Comment: It doesn't work.. $ git stash pop --index 1
fatal: ambiguous argument '1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Comment: warning on Poping your stashes

Comment: this worked for me in windows powershell

Answer (score 12):

Version 2.11+ use the following:

```
git stash list

git stash apply n
```

n is the number **stash@{12}**

Answer (score 11):

First check the list:-

```
git stash list
```

copy the index you wanted to pop from the stash list

```
git stash pop stash@{index_number}
```

eg.:

```
git stash pop stash@{1}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this answer a few times in this list, but just to be explicitly clear, at least as of git version 2.33.0, `git stash pop stash@{n}` [*is* valid](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-pop--index-q--quietltstashgt). No escaping necessary.

Comment: Might depend on the shell you use, right?

Comment: @silverdr Yeah I suppose that's possible. I'm just using whatever comes with the Git CLI for Windows within VS Code.

Comment: Yes, that explains. In some shells the curly braces need to be escaped or the whole argument quoted. Other than that this generally works