# Git: How to get stash before the last stash?

Tags: git, git-stash

I've been working on a branch in git, I then stashed some stuff. After some switching around branches I got back to my initial branch, made some new changes, stashed them, and then realised I wanted to go back to the changes I made before I stashed the first time.

So my question; is there a history of stashes, and if so, how do I get back to one of these?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git stash apply version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910082/git-stash-apply-version)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `git stash list` and choose appropriate stash in `git stash apply <stash-id>`

Comment: To show stash changes use `git stash show <stash-id>` and add `-p` to show the changed lines in the stash. 
`<stash-id>` would be in the format `stash@{1}` or `stash@{2}` etc